# Radio buttons are covering labels

Tags: jquery, css, html, radio-button, boolean

I am designing a simple form, which includes a boolean yes/no question. The code that I am using for this is

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

<input type="radio" name="bool" value="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="bool" value="no">No
```

When I load the page, the actual radio buttons appear in front of the Yes/No labels. I do not have sufficient rights to upload a picture of this unfortunately. How can I move the buttons to be next to the labels?

I have seen other people with similar problems and the solution seems to be to change the CSS, which I cannot do as my CSS comes from jquery

Comment: Please make the snippet show the issue - you can include a link to the image using `![text](imagelink)`

Comment: Upload a snippet, so that i will be clear to understand

Comment: just to ask the obvious: why don't you change the html?

Comment: Unclear what you asking, you want to reverse position of `radio` and `text` ?

Comment: The snippet is not showing the problem

Comment: Its hard to know without any information provided. But a quick solution would be to add `margin-left` or `padding-left`. I think the issue is with the absolute position of the element.

Comment: and I haven't changed the html because I don't know what to change it to. [Image on Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/110844844845534798035/6506802238879418642?authkey=CNKN6PSDureWDQ)

Comment: I now see your problem in the image. But this problem is not caused by the code you share.

Comment: If it helps, I am using class="ui-field-contain" as a div. I don't know what else could be causing the problem.

Comment: If it helps, all the div blocs are encapsulated in <fieldset class="ui-field-contain"> and all of this is within a form

Answer (score 0):

Try this - How can I move the buttons to be next to the labels?

example: Like this you can try

```
  <form>
  <label>Yes</label><input type="radio" name="bool" value="yes"><br>
  <label>No</label><input type="radio" name="bool" value="no">
  </form>
```

Comment: I have tried that, and it only moved the position of the radio buttons, but still [in front of the text](https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/110844844845534798035/6506803688869517442?authkey=CPDI1rDl9oOJdg)

Comment: LambertBrother means that in his case the input elements are overlapping the labels. He shows it in a partial screendump in the comments under his question.